# Only show features in visible layers when using the ArcMap hyperlink tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, hyperlink

I have an ArcMap MXD file with multiple layers containing points associated with an URL that can be visited using the hyperlink tool. Some layers contain many points, other contains few.

My problem is that when I select the hyperlink tool blue dots are displayed for all points, *even from layers that are not visible* (i.e. unchecked in the ToC). This makes it near impossible to click points in one of the layers containing few points, since the screen gets completely cluttered with points from the denser layers. The screenshot below illustrate the problem - only two of the blue dots are from points in the visible layer that I would actually like to click. Good luck finding them.

[image: Screenshot of map.]

Is there any way to make ArcMap only display blue dots for the visible layers? Limiting it to a selected layer would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: You could disable hyperlinks on the non visible layers or use the identify tool and launch the hyperlink from there.

Comment: @ChrisR Disabeling all the hyperlinks would be quite a manouver since it would require something along the lines of 5 clicks per layer... But using the identify tool instead is a great idea - thank you!

Comment: [...but the identify tool opens my links in IE. Argh.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154787/get-links-in-html-popup-in-arcmap-10-2-to-open-in-default-browser-instead-of-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using group layers? I was struggling myself but found that when the top group layer is unchecked but the sublayer is still checked, the hyperlink tool draws the sublayer in blue. Unchecking the sublayer removes the layer in the display.

You could also try to uncheck the highlight color for hyperlinks in the Customize->ArcMap otions->General tab. This removes the highlight color completely, so you can't see which layers are hyperlinked, but that may be to prefer if you know that already.

Comment: Both solution works like a charm! The checkbox thing sounds a bit like a bug to me. Thanks!